# What is the difference of sequence length and time step in recurrent neural network (RNN)?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, recurrent-neural-network

I am confused about the sequence length and time-step concept in recurrent neural networks (RNNs), what is the difference and connection of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the terminology of recurrent neural networks, you look at sequences which are typically denoted as

$$
x_{1:T} = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_T).
$$

Here, $T$ is the sequence length and a running variable $t$ is the time step. For example, you can write expressions such as

$$
x_1 = 2 \\
x_t = 2 x_{t-1}, t \neq 1.
$$